# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'version') while using vue-bootstrap

Tags: vue.js, npm, bootstrap-4, vuejs3, bootstrap-vue

I downloaded npm packages according to requirements from https://bootstrap-vue.org/vue3
so in package.json file I have:

```
"dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.23.1",
  },
```

In main.js I have:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

import { BootstrapVue} from 'bootstrap-vue'

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'

createApp(App).use(BootstrapVue).mount('#app')
```

I doesn't work. I get sush error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'version')

Answer (score 1):

This package isn't 100% compatible with Vue 3 yet. It's the vue 2 version running with a compatibility library to port it to Vue 3.

You need to install `@vue/compat` too, according to the same documentation you mentioned.

```
  "@vue/compat": "^3.2.41",
```

Look at their example [sandbox for Vue3](https://stackblitz.com/edit/bootstrap-vue-with-compat?file=main.js)

Comment: tried adding @vue/compat, didn't help. Also tried example  sandbox for Vue3, didn't help to.